# This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
                android:paddingTop="1.0dip"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <include layout="@layout/quickactions_buttons_part" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

but I get this warnings

```
This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view
```

and

```
This HorizontalScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless
```

Does anyone have any idea what can i do that this message wil go away?

Comment: You're using the FrameLayout to only host the LinearLayout, which makes it useless.

Comment: if it's useless, remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a single component (row) vertical linear layout, containing another linear layout. This does not make any sense as layout is a container for the multiple components. If there is only one component, such container is redundant and can be replaced directly by the single component it holds.

Same way, the second `LinearLayout` also makes no sense, holding a single component, the `HorizontalScrollView`. The only thing may matter there is the "80.0dip" property that needs to be specified on the component now.

Hence your layout is unnecessary sophisticated. The contents of the `FrameLayout` can be rewritten simpler as

```
<HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="80.0dip"
   android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
   android:paddingTop="1.0dip"
   android:scrollbars="none" >
   <include layout="@layout/quickactions_buttons_part" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

resulting the code that both runs faster and is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to FrameLayout, 1st LinerLayout and 2nd LinearLayout which are not solving any purpose while you have everything inside HorizontalScrollView.